# Chart.js ignoring fill to start

Tags: chart.js

I have a line chart made with Chart.js. It has positive and negative values. I want to 'fill' it with a background color, but to the bottom of graph–not to 0.

After reading the documentation I figured you'd need to set the `fill` property to `'start'`. But this doesn't seem to work?

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/euh5mbyq/). Below is a picture to explain.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/area.html):

> 2 prior version 2.6.0, boundary values was 'zero', 'top', 'bottom'
>   (deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this issue–don't be me. Check that you're using 2.6+ and not 2.4 like me.. ‍♂️